# Omit table name and dot in SELECT query

Tags: select, alias, hive

When I perform this query:

```
SELECT `tablename`.* FROM `something`.`tablename`
```

I get a table with column names that contain dots:

```
tablename.c1 | tablename.c2 | tablename.c3
------------------------------------------
     a       |       1      |     2
     b       |       1      |     3
```

I don't want this, I just want the column names `c1`, `c2` and `c3`, I can solve this by writing the following query:

```
SELECT `tablename`.`c1` as `c1`,
       `tablename`.`c2` as `c2`,
       `tablename`.`c3` as `c3` FROM `something`.`tablename`
```

I however have many columns which makes it a very long query. How can I rename the columns from the first query or how can I get this right from the start?

(p.s. the query I'm using contains multiple table references that is why I specify the table name `tablename.*`)

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
select 
  c1 
, c2 
, c3 
from tablename ;
```

With only one table involved, the database does not need to be *told* from which table the field should be taken.  If you were joining *two* tables that both contained, say, an `id` column, then you would have to tell the database (through the query) which one you wanted returned:

```
select 
  table1.id
, table1.field1 
, table2.field2 
from table1 
inner join table2 
on ... 
where ...
```

But even that's quite cumbersome. 
Enter "Correlation Names" - a shorthand naming, with each query, denoting which table is which:

```
select 
  a.id
, a.field1 
, b.field2 
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b 
on ... 
where ...
```

Do not worry about lengthy field names or listing lots of fields in your queries - that's exactly what you *should* be doing - *meaningful* field names and *only* retrieving the fields that you need in each query.

Never use "select *" in Production code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it the way you proposed in your question.

In cases of many columns, you can get the code generated for you. I find string manipulation in Excel really useful for generating SQL code.

Comment: As the OP says in his question, "the query I'm using contains multiple table references that is why I specify the table name".